# Understanding Blackwell's Approachability Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I'm not super solid on my linear algebra, so I am getting lost in the discussions of halfspaces. Can someone give me an intuitive explanation (possibly with a concrete toy problem) of Blackwell's Approachability Theorem, and the algorithm its proof constructs?